# Can't create package for WinUI 3 Packaged app with plain .NET library

Tags: c#, winui-3

I have WinUI 3 Packaged app targeting .NET 6 Windows with some libraries targeting .NET 6. With Debug everything is okay, but when I want create package (Solution Explorer -> Package project -> Publish -> Create app packages...) I get error, when I can't create package, because libraries don't have target for specific .NET from package (.NET6.0-windows...). Currently I solved it with duplicated libraries targeting windows .NET, but for future development it is absolutely impractical.

Error message:

`Assets file '{Path to specific project}\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.`

Is any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply multi-target your library-projects like changing

```html
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

to

```html
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything is now okay.